# Search API Autocomplete does not return any suggestions when input contains ąčęėįšųūž or similar characters

Tags: search

I am using Drupal 7, Solr 4.x, search_api, search_api_autocomplete modules in project. We have a page, which contains fulltext search with autocomplete settings. Problem is - it does not return any kind of results, when these contain non utf characters, for example ąčęėįšųūž.

Answer (score 1):

Install the [Transliteration](https://www.drupal.org/project/transliteration) module and enable the homonymous processor for the index.